# Connection between Interstellar and 'Flora's Letter'?

Tags: analysis, title, distribution, interstellar

I work in a cinema, and today we received our copy of Christopher Nolan's *Interstellar*: which came packaged and labelled as *"Flora's Letter"*

As is quite well known, film's are distributed (and sometimes produced) under [working titles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_title) or false titles, in order to interfere with potential pirates or thieves.

What is less well known, is that most film producers cannot resist the opportunity to leave clever clues and hints; almost like serial killers!

Even previous Nolan films have a precedent for this, being distributed as *Backbreaker* (The Dark Knight Rises) and *Be Kind, Rewind* (Memento)...

Which leads me to ask... What is the significance of 'Flora's Letter'?

Comment: Maybe that the Gnostic [Letter to Flora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_to_Flora) claims that the universe was created by an imperfect God... Or maybe I'm over-reaching and it's just the prevalent theory that the film is Nolan's letter to his daughter Flora. :)

Comment: @Walt!!! WRITE AS AN ANSWER! This is a good answer!

Comment: Nah, haven't seen the film yet, just the trailer, so not really qualified. But it's easy to imagine that Cooper & Murph parallel Nolan & Flora.

Comment: I'm testing the film today so I should know for sure if there's anything plot wise by tonight, but Damn: I think you may have cracked it, and only 15 mins after being posted! Well done.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson, edited to be clearer, but the DCP package is being distributed under the title *Flora's Letter*, yes

Comment: And excellent opening question for *Interstellar* week, of course.

Comment: Flora is also Nolan's daughter's name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was the working title of the film based on his daughters name:

> Nolan’s father died in 2009, after a year-long battle with cancer that was diagnosed just as the film-maker was finishing Inception, and as Jonah was starting to write Interstellar. His father’s diagnosis was “very much in my mind,” Jonah said, “the connection that you have with your parents. It was the background to much of it.” Nolan himself sees Interstellar more in terms of his relationship with his own children – Rory, Magnus, Oliver and Flora – all of whom have given him the working titles for the last four of his movies. The Dark Knight was “Rory’s First Kiss”, Inception was “Oliver’s Arrow”, The Dark Knight Rises was “Magnus Rex”, and Interstellar was “Flora’s Letter”

Source: [theguardian.com](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2014/nov/04/-sp-christopher-nolan-interstellar-rebooted-blockbuster)

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply... "Interstellar" is not a science-fiction movie.  It is a metaphor for the bond of love between a father and his daughter.

When Nolan initially interviewed McConaughey and Zimmer for the lead role and musical score, he told them nothing about the plot of the movie.  Instead, he discussed the love within family, particularly between a father and his daughter.

"Interstellar" is not science-fiction.  That's just a plot device.  It's about how parent-child love can transcend all boundaries.

Flora is Nolan's daughter.